# Looking for Arrests Data at a state level across years

Tags: data-request, usa, programming, crime

I just find out that R comes with a data about arrests in the US on its base package `USArrests`. This is a interesting data but only for the year 1973. Anybody knows if there is another package with a similar data but with longitudinal information?

Comment: Just as an aside, I think this data is purely for learning / experimenting purposes. There are more datasets like mtcars, women etc in R. Just saying don't take such data in the base package too seriously. *Not that you were!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is complete documented R code to work with all of the microdata that you are looking for

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20incident-based%20reporting%20system%20%28nibrs%29

Answer (score 3):

The FBI Crime Statistics/UCR data contains what you are looking for. They go back to at least 2005 (online). I think you will find what you want in Table 5, but there's lots to choice from:

http://www.fbi.gov/stats-services/crimestats

Answer (score 1):

virginia state police annual report from 1999-2013, in particular you want IX Arrest Totals data for Counties, Cities, Colleges and Universities, Other Agencies, Other Totals, and Total State datasets. vsp data s published here in pdf:
http://www.vsp.state.va.us/Annual_Report.shtm
i've actually been working on this set for a little while now, splitting them all up into .csv, .osd, and .xlsx, etc. and va crime is here:
https://github.com/jalbertbowden/va-crime